# Non-Linear Solubility Trend

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solubility

I am doing a lab on carbon dioxide solubility in water and I have a non-linear trend which seems to agree with the accepted trend. I am examining the change in solubility as a function of temperature. In the experiment I titrated carbonated water with sodium hydroxide and used molar ratios to determine the carbon dioxide content. The following graph shows the accepted trend:

[image: Solubility Curve]

(Graph from: http://www.rocketscientistsjournal.com/2006/10/co2_acquittal.html)

I've been thinking but, can't seem to figure out why the trend is non-linear. Is there any intuition behind this trend?

Comment: Nonlinear with respect to what? Amount of water? Amount of CO2? Temperature? Is it a closed system? Please be specific about what you are asking, as well as the experimental setup...

Comment: Sorry, it is updated now.

Answer (score 2):

The solubility can be thought of as an equilibrium. The Van 't Hoff Equation describes the relationship between any equilibrium constant and temperature.

$lnK_2 - lnK_1 = \frac{\Delta H }{R} (\frac{1}{T_1}-\frac{1}{T_2})$ . Thus, the graph is not linear.

Comment: I just fixed the equation --there was an extra negative.

Comment: Solubility is linearly proportional, however, to pressure.